# Understanding tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

So, I lately had a discussion about calculating

$$\mathbb{Z}\big/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}\big/n\mathbb{Z}$$

It turned out to be

$$\mathbb{Z}\big/gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$$

and I was understanding the argumentation, but still feel a lack of the actual structure of tensors over modules.

So my first question is, if there is a even more general concept of tensors than over modules? I don't like to understand this first for vector spaces, then rings, and so on. I like to grab the structure by the root and going on from there.

My second question is, if someone can recommend a short introduction text to tensors that points it out quite general and still gives enough examples to get the structure into one's hands.

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look on tensor product of *biacts*, i.e. two sided monoid actions. See e.g. my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428933/higher-level-view-of-construction-of-tensor-product/2433766?s=2|0.0000#2433766